# CSS radio button border how to remove it?

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I'm styling a generated contact form from the CMS we are using. Only problem i have is that i don't now how to remove the border on it. On input types you normaly do `border: none !important;` and than it's done. Only I have no idea on how to remove the border so I only have a white bullet and not that black border around it.

[image]

Above I put the picture. I wan't to remove that black border on it. How i can do this by using css?

**HTML**

```
<span class="cms-form-field" style="width: 60%;">
<label>
    <input class="cms-form-field-radio" type="radio" value="Ik wil extra informatie" data-error-message="" placeholder="" name="field_62" />
    Ik wil extra informatie
</label>
</br>
</span>
```

**CSS**

```
.cms-form-row input, 
.cms-form-row select, 
.cms-form-row textarea, 
.cms-form-field, 
.cms-form-label {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 3px;
}
.cms-form-field-radio {
    margin: 0 11px 0 0;
}
body, input, textarea {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
* {
    color: #2e3645;
    font-family: "museo-sans","Open Sans",sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you post your code please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's no way to remove the border completely ,yet you can change the border color or make yourself a custom style for your inputs like `[http://codepen.io/MightyShaban/pen/afDKe][1]` , or [this](http://code.stephenmorley.org/html-and-css/styling-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/) hope help you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is something for you; http://viralpatel.net/blogs/css-radio-button-checkbox-background